# How can i declare list of maps in golang

Tags: go

i am not getting how should i format the struct in golang so that i can get the list of maps (key/value pairs) in JSON format ?
So far i tried with this

```
package main

import (
"encoding/json"
"fmt"
)

func main() {
map1 := map[string]interface{}{"dn": "abc", "status": "live", "version": 2, "xyz": 3}
map2, _ := json.Marshal(map1)
fmt.Println(string(map2))
}
```

here it is just printing key/value pairs...

> {"dn":"abc","status":"live","version":2,"xyz":3}

but i need output something like this :

> [{"dn":"abc","status":"live"},{"version":2,"xyz":3}]

Comment: Use a slice of maps.

Comment: so if i understand it correctly, you needed an array of JSON?

Comment: yes. thanks . if you can please paste me some sample code.. i can take it forward

Comment: @user2315104, check this out https://gobyexample.com/json, i'm not sure though whether you have particular JSON structure in mind.

Comment: thanks. i tried with this, but not getting how to define list of maps and then push values in that struct so that after encoding i can get the json

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As suggested by @Volker, you should use slice of maps:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

// M is an alias for map[string]interface{}
type M map[string]interface{}

func main() {
    var myMapSlice []M

    m1 := M{"dn": "abc", "status": "live"}

    m2 := M{"version": 2, "xyz": 3}

    myMapSlice = append(myMapSlice, m1, m2)

    // or you could use `json.Marshal(myMapSlice)` if you want
    myJson, _ := json.MarshalIndent(myMapSlice, "", "    ")
    fmt.Println(string(myJson))
}
```

Outputs:

```
[
    {
        "dn": "abc",
        "status": "live"
    },
    {
        "version": 2,
        "xyz": 3
    }
]
```

From the code, I've used an alias for `map[string]interface{}` to make it more convenient to initialize a map of interface.

Link to code: https://play.golang.org/p/gu3xafnAyG

Comment: awesome .. got it

Comment: Here's how to do it without the extra types: ` myMapSlice := []map[string]interface{}{{"dn": "abc", "status": "live"},{"version": 2, "xyz": 3}}` [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/PU9oE-0vRR).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question, and answered myself (No `struct` usage for my case)

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    mapSlice := []map[string]interface{}{}

    map1 := map[string]interface{}{"foo": "bar"}
    mapSlice = append(mapSlice, map1)

    fmt.Println(mapSlice[0]["foo"]) // prints "bar"
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/BOCVAOngul2